# The Sword of Comfort

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I sit in your cubicle every day,
>
> Making you comfortable in my own way.
>
> You could say I'm sort of a sword in one sense;
>
> My job is to make one area light and another dense.
>
> I can't really win and I can't truly lose.
>
> You wouldn't want to be in my shoes.
>
> Cycling, cycling, cycling, all the day long,
>
> Singing my quiet, monotone, rhythm-filled song.
>
> My cousin, though, now he's pretty cool.
>
> He and his mates can fly - what a jewel!
>
> I've had three movies named after me, too!
>
> The were all kind of dark for me and my crew.
>
> But here I sit - take a look at me.
>
> I'm happy to serve you, you see,
>
> But I've collected far too much dust,
>
> And slowing me down to clean it is a must.
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you a

> BLADE?

I sit in your cubicle every day,

> Fan blades are in cubicles.

Making you comfortable in my own way.

> And make people comfortable by cooling them down

You could say I'm sort of a sword in one sense;

> They have blades, so they're sort of swords

My job is to make one area light and another dense.

> The area behind the fan blade gets lighter because it has its air sucked in, and the area in front is denser because the air is getting blown into that space?

I can't really win and I can't truly lose.

> True, there's no winning and losing for fan blades (as opposed to sports fans)

You wouldn't want to be in my shoes.

> Also true, you wouldn't want to be a fan blade

Cycling, cycling, cycling, all the day long,

> Fan blades rotate all day

Singing my quiet, monotone, rhythm-filled song.

> Fan noise is a white noise

My cousin, though, now he's pretty cool.

> A propeller?

He and his mates can fly - what a jewel!

> Propellers can fly

I've had three movies named after me, too!

> [Blade](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120611/), [Blade II](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0187738/), and [Blade: Trinity](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0359013/) are all named after Blade.

The were all kind of dark for me and my crew.

> They're all action/horror movies.

But here I sit - take a look at me.

> Fan blades sit on the desk

I'm happy to serve you, you see,

> And serve people who use them

But I've collected far too much dust,

> If you don't clean fan blades they get dusty

And slowing me down to clean it is a must.

> And it's a must to clean them otherwise the dust goes everywhere

What am I?

> A blade!

Comment: Very close! I was afraid this one was going to be too easy...Just need to alter the word a bit to fit the movie clue.

Comment: How does this edit look? (first line)? @Brandon_J

Comment: 2fast4me.... :) good job!